# How to access QML ListView delegate items from C++?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

In *Listview*, I have popping up 100's of items using "*delegate*", assume that, listview already displayed populated value. **Now I would like to extract already displayed values in QML List view from C++**. How to achieve this?
Note:
**I can not access datamodel directly,** since I am doing filtration in delegate using *hidden* variable

```
        /*This is not working code, Please note,
        delegate will not display all model data.*/
        ListView
        {
        id:"listview"
           model:datamodel
           delegate:{
                      if(!hidden)
                      {
                        Text{        
                        text:value
                      }
                    }

        }


 //Can I access by using given approach?
 QObject * object =   m_qmlengine->rootObjects().at(0)->findChild<QObject* >("listview");

//Find objects
const QListObject& lists = object->children();

//0 to count maximum
//read the first property
QVarient value =  QQmlProperty::read(lists[0],"text");
```

Comment: You should start at least with a code that works. Also, you should keep access from C++ to QML to a minimum, most certainly not in this case. If you want the model data on the C++ side, use a C++ model.

Comment: I am doing automation testing, I cannot use model data for validation,  so after display list view in qml, I need to extract the data from qml to C++ and validate.

Comment: I doubt it will work as you expect, you will have better chances iterating the listview in QML and sending the text to C++ by passing it to a slot function.

Comment: Since i am doing automation testing, i canot edit/touch on qml, instead I use qml plugin,  so that application wont be disturbed with automation testing code.

Comment: Do your QML tests in QML: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-qtquicktest.html

Comment: I can manage to use QML for QML test, I have used QML plugin for the same. above comment is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for a specific item in QML with the [`objectName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) **property**. Let's take a look at a simple QML file:

```
//main.qml
Window {
    width: 1024; height: 768; visible: true
    Rectangle {
        objectName: "testingItem"
        width: 200; height: 40; color: "green"
    }
}
```

And in C++, assume `engine` is the `QQmlApplicationEngine` that loads main.qml, we can easily find `testingItem` by searching the QObject tree from QML root item using [`QObject::findChild`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

```
//C++
void printTestingItemColor()
{
    auto rootObj = engine.rootObjects().at(0); //assume main.qml is loaded
    auto testingItem = rootObj->findChild<QQuickItem *>("testingItem");
    qDebug() << testingItem->property("color");
}
```

However, this method cannot find all items in QML since some items may not have QObject parent. For example, delegates in `ListView` or `Repeater`:

```
ListView {
    objectName: "view"
    width: 200; height: 80
    model: ListModel { ListElement { colorRole: "green" } }
    delegate: Rectangle {
        objectName: "testingItem" //printTestingItemColor() cannot find this!!
        width: 50; height: 50
        color: colorRole
    }
}
```

For delegates in `ListView`, we have to search the [visual child](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html) instead of the object child. [`ListView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) delegates *are parented to ListView's `contentItem`*. So in C++ we have to search for the `ListView` first (with `QObject::findChild`), and then search for delegates in `contentItem` using [`QQuickItem::childItems`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#childItems):

```
//C++
void UIControl::printTestingItemColorInListView()
{
    auto view = m_rootObj->findChild<QQuickItem *>("view");
    auto contentItem = view->property("contentItem").value<QQuickItem *>();
    auto contentItemChildren = contentItem->childItems();
    for (auto childItem: contentItemChildren )
    {
        if (childItem->objectName() == "testingItem")
            qDebug() << childItem->property("color");
    }
}
```