# How to access QML delegate children of a ListView from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML ListView and I want to access to the delegate children in c++

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    objectName: "wnd1"
    ListView {
        objectName: "mediaPlayerListView"
        model: provider.mediaPlayerItems
        delegate: MediaPlayerDelegate
    }
}
```

MediaPlayerDelegate.qml

```
Row {
    objectName: "mainRow"

    VideoOutput {
      objectName: "videoOutput" + modelData.id
}
```

Here is the c++ code I've tried

```cpp
QString currentId = "1";

QQuickWindow *mainWindow = _qmlAppEngine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickWindow *>("wnd1");

QObject *mediaPlayerListView = mainWindow->findChild<QObject *>("mediaPlayerListView");

QObject *mediaPlayerListViewDelegate = mediaPlayerListView->property("delegate").value<QObject *>();
```

I want to be able to get in cpp the videoOutput, doing something like this

```cpp
QObject *videoOutput = mediaPlayerListViewDelegate->findChild<QObject *>("videoOutput" + currentId)
```

But I can't access further than the delegate, it has no children.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767512/how-to-access-qml-listview-delegate-items-from-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access QML ListView delegate items from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767512/how-to-access-qml-listview-delegate-items-from-c)